# Azure Pipelines second job does not find results of first job

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines

I am getting started with azure-pipelines.yml

I wanted to have 2 jobs within the same stage. One to build a solution and the other to run unit tests.

The problem is that the second job executed a script step and it does not find a folder `Release` that the previous one should have created:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'

stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
    - script: dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - script: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
  - job: UnitTests
    dependsOn: Build
    steps:
    - script: dotnet vstest test/*UnitTests/bin/Release/**/*UnitTests.dll
```

However if I add all the steps within the same job it works:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'

stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
    - script: dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - script: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - script: dotnet vstest test/*UnitTests/bin/Release/**/*UnitTests.dll
```

I cannot find an answer on why a dependent job cannot find on the file system the folders that a previous one has generated. Any explanation or link to something that clarifies that would be much appreciated.

I have used gitlab in the past and I don't recall a similar behavior although I don't know whether it had the concept of job as a different thing to steps.

Comment: Have you tried using a "Publish Pipeline Artifact" task? MS introduced this to pass artifacts between jobs.

Comment: Would it be a problem if all the steps were part of a single job? That does look like the best solution for you, to be honest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key element that you are missing is that jobs run on independent agents (separate computers) and do not have any kind of shared filesystem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Any files created in one job that you want to make available on a dependent job must be explicitly staged (in job 'A') and then explicitly downloaded (in job 'B').

See publish:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

And download:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

Comment: what about files created in the same Job of the same Stage (and, implicity, on the same agent?). Is possible share a file between different steps of the same job?