# How to share an Azure Devops job result when the only shared repository requires a different type of Task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Unfortunately the results of one job can not be viewed by another job *even in the same Stage*.  This Q&A talks about it: [Azure Pipelines second job does not find results of first job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685399/azure-pipelines-second-job-does-not-find-results-of-first-job)

> The key element that you are missing is that jobs run on independent agents (separate computers) and do not have any kind of shared filesystem.

I do not have a solution for our current situation since the job runs `bash` commands in a `Bash2` *Task* type. But then the only shared repository/file system is `Azure BlobStore`.  our authentication mechanism requires using `AzureCLI@2` *Task* type to upload the file to BlobStore.  So we don't have a way to both of the following in the same `job`:

a. Do the work (`Bash`)
b. Upload the work (`AzureCLI`)

What can be done here?

Comment: You can publish your artifact in one job and then consume it in another job. that's a common scenario in such solutions. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: @Sibtain  thx that's spot-on. Pls consider to make an answer

Comment: Done, let me know if you need more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that jobs are independent in Azure DevOps, so you should consider publishing your artifacts in one job and then consume them in another job.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more details.